# Retrieving the value of _id via mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, export

I need to export a mongo collection to CSV. I'm using mongoexport with something like:

```
mongoexport --db myDb --collection myCollection --fields _id,myField1,myField2 --csv --out myExport.csv
```

How to get the value of `_id` instead of `ObjectID(509b82904eb8dd3621000008)` for each line in the export?

Comment: What value are you expecting .. just "509b82904eb8dd3621000008" for an ObjectID?

Comment: Yes, this is it since I only need a simple data export; I don't want to have to post-process the resulting sheet. But unfortunately, for what I've seen so far, that's not possible.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles across this years later (like me just now): it still seems there's no easily solution.